# flutter sqflite update method not working? No error thrown

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Trying to update an existing case in a table where the intention serves as the unique identifier. There are no errors thrown but upon retrieving that element again, it doesn't look to have been updated.

Heres my code (pretty new so sorry if its not following conventions):

database creation (in sql_helper.dart)

```
library sql_helper;

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:timer3/models/session_chunk.dart';

var database;

// creates database
initDatabase() async {
  database = openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'session_database.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
    return db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE session(intention STRING PRIMARY KEY, workTime INT, breakTime INT, progress STRING)');
  }, version: 1);
}
```

data model

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:timer3/database/sql_helper.dart';

// This class represents one session chunk and are compiled together to
// create a session
class SessionChunk {
  String intention = "";
  int workTime = 0;
  int breakTime = 0;
  String progress = "";

  //constructor requires intention to create
  SessionChunk({required intention, workTime, breakTime, progress}) {
    this.intention = intention;
  }

  // class methods
  updateWorkTime({required int workTime}) {
    this.workTime += workTime;
    //TODO write a push method for updates
  }

  updateBreakTime({required int breakTime}) {
    this.breakTime += breakTime;
  }

  updateProgress({required String progress}) {
    this.progress = progress;
  }

  // converts instance variables to a map for
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "intention": this.intention,
      "workTime": this.workTime,
      "breakTime": this.breakTime,
      "progress": this.progress
    };
  }

  //print out the curretn chunk state
  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return toMap().toString();
  }
}
```

method that tries to update it (in helper file)

```
updateLastChunk() async {
  final db = await database;
  SessionChunk lastChunk = await grabLastChunk();

  lastChunk.updateWorkTime(workTime: 50);

  print("this is the new value");
  print(lastChunk.toMap());

  //TODO: this isn't working
  await db.update('session', lastChunk.toMap(),
      where: 'intention = ?', whereArgs: [lastChunk.intention]);

  print('update done');
}
```

here is the output, notice how reading that row after the update had no effect and the values stay 0 despite it passing through 50.

Let me know if you see the problem as I've been looking with no luck!

Comment: Any luck on this? Facing a similar issue.